# Updating table without replacing values that already exist in the original table with null values from the temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an original table named 'student' like this:

```
idstudent    studentname    studentclass
101          adam           A
102          brian          NULL
103          charlie        C 
104          danny          D
```

Then, I have a temporary table name 'student_temp' like this:

```
idstudent    studentname    studentclass
101          adam           A
102          brian          B
103          NULL           C
105          edward         E
```

If I run this query on SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2:

```
USE [StudentDatabase]
GO

UPDATE stu
SET [studentname] = tmp.[studentname]
  , [studentclass] = tmp.[studentclass]

FROM [StudentDatabase].[dbo].[student] stu
INNER JOIN [StudentDatabase].[dbo].[student_temp] tmp  
    ON stu.[idstudent] = tmp.[idstudent]
GO

INSERT INTO student
SELECT 
    tmp.[idstudent]
  , tmp.[studentname]
  , tmp.[studentclass]

FROM [StudentDatabase].[dbo].[student] stu
RIGHT OUTER JOIN [StudentDatabase].[dbo].[student_temp] tmp 
    ON  stu.[idstudent] = tmp.[idstudent]
WHERE stu.[idstudent] IS NULL
```

The results of 'student' table will be like this:

```
idstudent    studentname    studentclass
101          adam           A
102          brian          B
103          NULL           C
104          danny          D
105          edward         E
```

But what I want is, the results will be like this:

```
idstudent    studentname    studentclass
101          adam           A
102          brian          B
103          charlie        C
104          danny          D
105          edward         E
```

Notice that `idstudent=103` in `student` table already have `studentname` value "charlie". But it is replaced by records from `student_temp` table that it is `NULL`.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: If both tables have non-null values that are unequal, which one should be preferred?

Comment: The preferred one is student_temp table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE stu
SET [studentname] = CASE WHEN tmp.[studentname] IS NOT NULL THEN tmp.[studentname] ELSE stu.studentname END
  , [studentclass] = CASE WHEN tmp.[studentclass] IS NOT NULL THEN tmp.[studentclass] ELSE stu.studentclass END

FROM [student] stu
INNER JOIN [student_temp] tmp  
    ON stu.[idstudent] = tmp.[idstudent]
GO

INSERT INTO student
SELECT 
    tmp.[idstudent]
  , tmp.[studentname]
  , tmp.[studentclass]

FROM [student] stu
RIGHT OUTER JOIN [student_temp] tmp 
    ON  stu.[idstudent] = tmp.[idstudent]
WHERE stu.[idstudent] IS NULL
```

---

Comment: Those `CASE` expressions are a very verbose way of doing the same thing that `COALESCE` does.

Answer (score 1):

Use a condition in your `WHERE` clause to ignore `NULL` values

```
UPDATE stu
SET [studentname] = tmp.[studentname]
  , [studentclass] = tmp.[studentclass]

FROM [StudentDatabase].[dbo].[student] stu
INNER JOIN [StudentDatabase].[dbo].[student_temp] tmp  
    ON stu.[idstudent] = tmp.[idstudent]
WHERE tmp.[studentname] IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

This whole thing should generally be done with a [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb510625.aspx) and [`COALESCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190349.aspx):

```
MERGE INTO student t
USING student_temp s
ON t.idstudent = s.idstudent
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  studentname = COALESCE(t.studentname,s.studentname),
  studentclass = COALESCE(t.studentclass,s.studentclass)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (idstudent,studentname,studentclass)
VALUES (s.idstudent,s.studentname,s.studentclass);
```

This currently favours existing data if both tables have non-null values. If you'd prefer to overwrite with new values from `student_temp` then reverse the order of values inside the `COALESCE` expressions.

So, to prefer values from `student_temp`:

```
MERGE INTO student t
USING student_temp s
ON t.idstudent = s.idstudent
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  studentname = COALESCE(s.studentname,t.studentname),
  studentclass = COALESCE(s.studentclass,t.studentclass)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (idstudent,studentname,studentclass)
VALUES (s.idstudent,s.studentname,s.studentclass);
```

Comment: There is an error saying `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'. `